# Is there a way finding distribution of objects without detecting them?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

Suppose my data consists of images of bubbles, and the labels are histograms describing the distribution of sizes, for example:

```
0-10mm 10% 
10-20mm 30%
20-30mm 40%
30-40mm 20%
```

It is important to note that -

- All size percentages sum to 100%.
- I don't have annotated data, so i can't train an object detector and then just calculate the distribution by counting objects detected. However, i do have a feature extractor train on my data.

I thought about implementing a simple CNN followed by FC layer, and then applying softmax on the logits. However, softmax is more suitable for classification tasks, and i am afraid that the exponent in the equation will "throw" larger values to 1 and smaller values to 0[image].

Are there any recommended arcitectures/loss functions/normalization functions that are suitable for this type of problem?

Comment: Softmax produces only values between 0 a 1, and that they sum to one, so its exactly the output activation you need.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is. But Larger values tend to get much higher percentage because of the exponent.

Comment: I don't see why that is a problem, in the end the model learns what to input to softmax.

Comment: Even if you do a perfect job of identifying individual bubbles and counting them, this task is very likely to produce biases, depending on how the image is taken and what kind of image we're talking about in the first place. Could you post an example image?

Answer (score 1):

To me the softmax approach makes sense. Otherwise you can use a custom layer which divides every element of the vector by the sum of all the elements so that the sum of the result is 1.

As for the loss function, since you need something to compare 2 probability distributions, I think the Kullback Leibler divergence is something to try.

Comment: Could you please explain your intuition to why softmax makes sense for this task? Thank you.

Comment: "you can use a custom layer which divides every element of the vector by the sum of all the elements so that the sum of the result is 1." but what if my values logits can be negative?

Comment: You are right that negative numbers are a problem. I guess softmax is at least something to try. It's the only way I'm aware of to get a probability distribution out of K real numbers. Hopefully the training process will adjust weights so that the output is not too much biased towards small/big values.